# Mod_rewrite htaccess rule with exception for specific files not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
AcceptPathInfo On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%2 [L,R=301]
```

Here is my site structure:

```
 error_log
 lib/
 mail/
 public_html/
 www/
 access-logs/
 etc/
```

The `.htaccess` file is located inside `public_html`
Inside `public_html` I have `/assets`, `/images` and `/uploads`:

The rules redirect ok for /assets and /images but for :

```
http://www.domain.com/uploads/100_100/2014/10/24/5/0/841453939422001907988782-1-100_100.jpg
```

Redirects to www.domain.com.

EDIT: Entry from access_log below:

```
ip - - [24/Oct/2014:17:54:37 +0300] "GET /uploads/100_100/2014/10/13/d/2/80550090151440232989044-1-100_100.jpg HTTP/1.1" 301 20 "http://www.domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ch$
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log to see what the error is. It could be 404

Comment: @anubhava No, the access-logs clearly issue a 301 redirect, so basically it renders one of the redirect rules true. Which one, don't know :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be in your redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Also keep this rule just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Did what you say, it still redirects, check out my edit!

Comment: Do you have more rules or any other .htaccess in `/uploads/` folder?

Comment: The other rules are deflation rules. nothing mod_rewrite related and in /uploads i only have directories that represent image resolutions and date such as /100_100 , 290_290 and so forth

Comment: ok open Firebug and visit `http://www.domain.com/uploads/100_100/2014/10/24/5/0/841453939422001907988782-1-100_100.jpg` and see what redirects you get in Net tab.

Comment: 301 redirect index.php

Comment: Rename this .htaccess to something else and see if that changes behavior

Comment: Yes it changes behaviour, it fives 501 whenever i mess things up and restart apache

Comment: If there is no .htaccess how can it be 501 or restart apache? You need to cleanup some mess at your end it seems.

Comment: I don't need to delete hraccess to test if it's parsed. I never deleted it. It just a matter of rules.

Comment: Don't know what your last comment meant. Where is delete thing coming from? I was asking that when there is no .htaccess in `DocumentRoot` how can you get 501 and Apache restart scenario?

Comment: I don't need to rename/delete the file in order to test if it's parsed. If i mess a rule, after i issue apache restart i get 501 as normal. It's enough to test it's functionality.

Comment: First thing messing up .htaccess causes 500 not 501. Secondly rename .htaccess test is to know what is causing redirect of images, not to test anything else.